# How can I specify file locations using subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am using subprocess to run multiple python scripts:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run("python3 script1.py & python3 script2.py", shell=True)
```

How can I specify the script file locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```py
# main.py

import subprocess

subprocess.run(
    "python3 script1.py & python3 script2.py",
    cwd='my_dir',
    shell=True,
)
```

```
$ tree .      
.
├── main.py
└── my_dir
    ├── script1.py
    └── script2.py

1 directory, 3 files

$cat my_dir/script1.py
print('script1')

$cat my_dir/script2.py
print('script2')
```

For more complicated case:

```py
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).parent

import subprocess

subprocess.run(
    "python3 script1.py & python3 script2.py",
    cwd=BASE_DIR / 'my_dir',
    shell=True,
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I typed: import subprocess subprocess.run ("python3 script1.py & python3 script2.py",cwd=r'C:\Users\David\Automated_Tasks',shell=True,). I'm getting an error which says "NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid". Perhaps I've misunderstood something.

Comment: Please check the directory first and use `pathlib` or `os` to resolve the path string.

Comment: Apologies. There was indeed a mistake I made when typing the file directory. I've update it, no errors when running the script now. But the individual script itself doesn't run. I'm not sure why. Here is a follow up questions I posted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71997718/why-is-my-python-script-not-running-when-using-subprocess