# Why is my subprocess script not running my selenium python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, subprocess

I'm trying to run multiple Python scripts using subprocess. As a trial I just wanted to see if one script would run. The script is currently on the Desktop. I am using Spyder to run my script. I run my script with the following code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(
"python3 script1.py",
cwd=r'C:\Users\David\Desktop',
shell=True,
)
```

I don't receive any errors when I run this but the script1.py itself doesn't run. I know this because the script1.py is a selenium code which is supposed to download a file from a website but it doesn't download the file when I use the code above. Any ideas as to what could be going wrong?.

If you would like to test it out for yourself. Here is **script1.py**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options=Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

params={'behavior':'allow','downloadPath':r'C:\Users\David\Downloads'}
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.setDownloadBehavior',params)

driver.get("https://data.gov.uk/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/form/div/div/input"))).send_keys("Forestry Statistics 2018: Recreation")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/form/div/div/div/button"))).click()


WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/form/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/h2/a"))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/main/div/div/div/section/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a"))).click()
```

Comment: Use ```\\``` in place of ```\``` in your path.

Comment: It didn't change anything unfortunately. The above script run with no errors like before. But script1.py didn't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["python3", "C:/Users/David/Desktop/script1.py"], shell=True)
```

Edit: I have used `Popen` like this and it seemed to work fine. Try `Popen` maybe:

```
subprocess.Popen(["python3", "C:/Users/David/Desktop/script1.py"], shell=True)
```

Edit2: The problem was solved by changing `python3` to `python`.

Comment: You forgot a `"` after `python3`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but unfortunately script1.py still didn't run.

Comment: I have included script1.py into the original question now if anyone would like to have a go.

Comment: I just tried the Popen method but it still doesn't work unfortunately. I've added the script1.py file above if you'd like to try.

Comment: @DavidCopperfield Are you sure that you have python3 and not python?

Comment: I am currently using Spyder via Anaconda. It says: Python 3.8 when I launch it. I assumed it's Python3. Please bear in mind that I'm relatively new to Python.

Comment: @DavidCopperfield Try changing the python3 to python.

Comment: Wow. Worked with the one script. I'm going to try running it with multiple scripts now. Thanks!

Comment: Is this syntax correct for two scripts: subprocess.run(["python", "C:/Users/David/Desktop/script1.py","C:/Users/David/Desktop/script2.py"], shell=True)?. script1 runs but script2 doesn't.

Comment: You have to start two of them like this:
`subprocess.run(["python", "C:/Users/David/Desktop/script1.py"], shell=True)`
`subprocess.run(["python", "C:/Users/David/Desktop/script2.py"], shell=True)`

Comment: Look up https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html for more info

Comment: Thanks. I posted a follow up question if you'd like to take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72001426/how-can-i-adjust-my-python-subprocess-code-so-that-the-python-scripts-run-in-par?noredirect=1#comment127225985_72001426